# modolus factors with array

Tags: java, arrays

so I have an array which holds various numbers which include 3 and 5. I am passing in the number 45 so the result of this method should be 3 and 5 being printed however this is not working, does anyone know why?

```
 public void primeFactors(int n)
{
    //header
    System.out.println("\nprime factors of " +n+ " are:");

    for (int i = 1; i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%this.numbersinset[i] ==0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `numbersinset` contain?

Comment: I got it fixed, I had the print statement prinitng the index and not the contents of the array - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to make the cycle start from 0? Also it seems you need to call:

```
System.out.println(numbersinset[i]);
```

Instead of simply printing `i`.

Comment: same outcome :( any other issue you can see?

Comment: **What** is the outcome?

Comment: oh now I see, the print was off, thanks :)

Comment: sorry that was a horrible oversight lol